# Previous occurrence of element in DOM using JQuery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm wondering how to get the previous occurrence of a selector from an element regardless of where it is in the DOM tree. I'm assuming that the previous occurrence is not one of my original element's children.

Example:

```
<body>
    <p class="somethingImportant">Important</p>
    <h1>
        <p class="somethingImportant">Important too!</p>
    </h1>

    <table>
        <tr>
            <td id="start">Starting from here!</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

I want to get the `<p class="somethingImportant">Important too!</p>` element, starting from the `<td id="start">` element.

I've tried using the `prev()` and `next()` in JQuery, but they only get immediate siblings. I tried the `closest()` one too, but that only gets ancestors. Notice how the element I want is a child of an ancestor.

So, I tried something like `$("#start").closest(".somethingImportant").find(".somethingImportant")` and JQuery didn't return any results, mainly because `closest()` didn't I guess.

I want something like `prevAll(".somethingImportant").last()`, just without the immediate sibling limitation.

Has anyone else ran into this problem?

---

**EDIT**

The problem I'm trying to solve is how to get the previous "page" or the previous "heading" from a start element. The start element is a "cursor" that highlights the node I'm on. I'll have the view scroll to that element later in my code.

Here is a situation that it starts becoming a problem:

```
<p class="pageNumber">1</p>

<h1>Kinds of Animals</h1>

<p>Here are different kinds of animals:</p>

<table>
    <tr><td>Duck</td><td>Giraffe</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Anteater</td><td><span id="highlight">Badger</span></td></tr>
</table
```

I'm starting from `` `<span id="highlight"> ``.  I want to get the previous element that matches the JQuery selector `p.pageNumber, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6` no matter where it is nested in the DOM, as long as it's before the highlight. The selector matches all of the elements that I recognize as heading elements.

In this case, it should return `<h1>Kinds of Animals</h1>`.

---

**Code Samples**

Using Lee's solution, I was able to build a function that does a pretty good, yet elegant job of what I wanted it to do.

```
function GetPreviousOccurrence(elemSel, sel) {
    var selector = elemSel + ", " + sel;
    var prev;
    $(selector).each(function() {
        if ($(this).is(elemSel)) {
            return false;
        }
        prev = this;
    });

    return prev;
}
```

In my case, `elemSel = "#highlight";` and `sel = "p.pageNumber, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5 , h6";` It might not be super performant, but at least it reads nice.

*Extra Note:* Lee's addendum is better.

Comment: the example you gave is a poor example, ID's must be unique, and your p tag isn't closed.

Comment: It's also not valid to have a `<p>` inside of a `<p>`. The browser will throw it out.

Comment: I'd start by making your IDs unique...

Comment: Sorry, I'll make my example a little more realistic. Editing now...

Comment: No, not a little more realistic. Make it represent the actual problem.

Comment: Agreed with @CrazyTrain -- Also, if your elements have ID's, there's no need to traverse the DOM, just target the ID and go from there.

Comment: you can make use of `.parent()`

Comment: I tried to simplify it, but it obviously didn't work. I'll put up my original intent in my edit. I'm sorry to be roundabout like this.

Comment: DOM traversal is simple. You go up to ancestors, sideways to siblings, and down to descendants. Is `.somethingImportant` an ancestor of `#start`? No. Is `table`? Yes. Is the `h1` a sibling of `table`? Yes. Is your targeted element a descendant of the `h1`? Yes.

Comment: I gotta say I see these parent/sibling questions a lot. I'm always confused why the solution isn't just to add a class (or ID) to the specific elements you want to retrieve, and then reference those. It's a much more extensible solution.

Comment: @Katana314 Notice in this question the answer changes as the "start" point changes (when the user clicks stuff). OP has a collection of elements and wants to ignore the ones below the "start" point. You could mark it at the same time you mark "start" but the search would be the same before or after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will get a list of the DOM elements including those among which you want to find previous and the one you mention. I'm assuming you change the funky `<p>` elements to `<div>` and the id becomes a class:

```
var prev;
$(".start, .somethingImportant").each(function () {
    if ($(this).hasClass("start")) {
        return false;
    }
    prev = this;
});

... now '$(prev)' contains the previous elemnent you wanted 
...  or 'undefined' if there are none.
```

You get all the elements. jQuery does it in DOM order. Iterate through and when you find the 'start' element, the previous one is the one you wanted.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/aTat5/2/)

Note that with your example, this would work since there are no 'important' elements after the start element:

```
$(".somethingImportant:last")
```

**Addendum**

Another thought I had based on OP's solution function.

```
// Call this way
var $prev = GetPreviousOccurrence($("#highlight"), $("p.pageNumber, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5 , h6"));


function GetPreviousOccurrence($elemSel, $sel) {
    var selector = $elemSel.add($sel);
    var $prev;
    $(selector).each(function() {
        if ($(this).is($elemSel)) {
            return false;
        }
        $prev = $(this);
    });

    return $prev;
}
```

[ANOTHER FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/aTat5/3/)

Comment: That's actually pretty cool. I'll try it out an see how it goes.

Comment: I suppose I'm voted down for leaving outs some parens before. Seems silly when the question is for "how" and the code, even without parens, tells "how". Ah, thats SO.

Comment: It was for the "how." Anyway, you were a life-saver. I'll post the function I'm using that generalizes what you suggested.